# MATLAB Plot - Legend entry for multiple data rows - getcolumn

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, legend

Consider the following example:

```
x = magic(3);
figure(1); clf(1);
plot( x, '-r', 'DisplayName', 'Magic' );
legend( 'show' );
```

The resulting legend entries in MATLAB **R2014a** are
*getcolumn(Magic,1)*
*getcolumn(Magic,2)*
*getcolumn(Magic,3)*

The problem stems from `function [leg,labelhandles,outH,outM] = legend(varargin)` in `legend.m` (*Copyright 1984-2012 The MathWorks, Inc.*), line 628:
`str{k} = get(ch(k),'DisplayName');`
More specifically, the function `get`

- prepends `getcolumn(` and
- appends `, <Column Number>)`.

Is there an easy way to display exactly one legend entry (or multiple, but without the pre- and appended strings) for multiple data rows named after [`DisplayName`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/specify-legend-descriptions-during-line-creation.html), which have the same visual properties?

An alternative would of course be to programatically create multiple (or one) legend entries through plot handles (see below), but I would like to keep things short and simple.

One entry:

```
x = magic(3);
figure(1); clf(1);
h = plot( x, '-r' );
legend( h(1), 'Magic' );
```

Multiple entries:

```
x = magic(3);
figure(1); clf(1);
h = plot( x, '-r' );
strL = cell( 1, numel(h) );
for k = 1:numel(h)
    strL{k} = sprintf( 'Magic %d', k );
end
legend( h, strL );
```

---

*In MATLAB **R2014b**, the problem with getcolumn(Name,Row) does not appear anymore for the first code example.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set multiple display names for the legend entries in short syntax, you just need to prepare a cell array with them, let's say it's called `leg_names`, and then use [`set`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html?s_tid=doc_ta#f67-575595) to apply them to all at once:

```
set(p,{'DisplayName'},leg_names);
```

Let's take a look at an example:

```
x = magic(3); % your data
p = plot( x,'-r'); % plot and get an array of handles to the lines
% create a list of the desired names for the legend entries:
leg_names = [repmat('Magic ',size(x,2),1) num2str((1:size(x,2)).')];
set(p,{'DisplayName'},cellstr(leg_names)); % set all display names
legend('show'); % show the legend
```

The result is exactly as in your examples at the end of the question.

Also, note that the syntax: `[lgd,icons,plots,txt] = legend(___)` is not recommended ([from the docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html?s_tid=doc_ta#zmw57dd0e561948)):

> **Note:**   This syntax is not recommended. It creates a legend that does not support all graphics features. Instead, use the `lgd = legend(__)` syntax to return the Legend object and set Legend Properties.